# Chain style html markup

Tags: html, ruby, templates, chaining

**Motivation and Problem**

There are several libraries for generating html markup strings using ruby (erb, haml, builder, markaby, tagz, ...), but I am not satisfied with any of them. The reason is that, except for erb, they take the nesting style rather than the chain style. And erb is a way to embed ruby within html rather than generating html with ruby.

To my understanding, one beauty of ruby lies in encouraging the use of chain style:

```
receiver.method1(args1).method2(args2). ... method_n(args_n)
```

instead of doing a nesting style:

```
method_n(...method2(method1(receiver, args1), args2), ... args_n)
```

But libraries mentioned above (except for erb) take the nesting style (sometimes with the help of block arguments).

**My Idea**

For my own purpose, I wrote a method `dom` so that I can do html markup in a chain style. When applied to a string, this example

```
"This is a link to SO".dom(:a, href: "http://stackoverflow.com").dom(:body).dom(:html)
```

will generate:

```
<html><body><a href="http://stackoverflow.com";>This is a link to SO</a></body></html>
```

When applied to an array, this:

```
[
  ["a".dom(:td), "b".dom(:td)].dom(:tr),
  ["c".dom(:td), "d".dom(:td)].dom(:tr)
].dom(:table, border: 1)
```

will generate

```
<table border="1";>
  <tr>
    <td>"a"</td>
    <td>"b"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"c"</td>
    <td>"d"</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

And, when applied without an explicit receiver (outside of a domain of strings and arrays),

```
dom(:img, src: "picture.jpg", width: 48, height: 48)
```

will generate

```
<img src="picture.jpg";width="48";height="48";/>
```

Note that all is done with just one method `dom`. This is much simpler than using other libraries. It is also flexible in that it is not affected by a change in the inventory of html tags; you just specify that with a symbol argument. In other libraries, there are classes and/or methods for each tag. Furthuremore, unlike erb, it is pure ruby. It is not a DSL that needs to be convertred.

**My Implementation**

The implementation is as follows:

```
class Hash
    def attribute
        map{|k, v| %Q{#{k}#{
            case v
            when TrueClass; ''
            when Hash;       %Q{="#{v.subattribute}"}
            else             %Q{="#{v}"}
            end
        ;}}}.join
    end
    def subattribute
        map{|k, v| %Q{#{k}:#{v};}}.join
    end
end

class Array
    def dom type, hash = {}
        "<#{type} #{hash.attribute}>\n#{join("\n").gsub(/^/, "  ")}\n</#{type}>"
    end
end

class String
    def dom type, hash = {}
        "<#{type} #{hash.attribute}>#{self}</#{type}>"
    end
end

class Object
    def dom type, hash = {}
        "<#{type} #{hash.attribute}/>"
    end
end
```

**Questions**

- Are there already stable libraries that do a similar thing?
- What will be the potential problems to this approach (particularly to my implementation or to doing this in chain approach)?
- Some attributes take boolean values, which are often encouraged to be omitted. For example, `<input type="text";readonly>` instead of `<input type="text";readonly="true">`. In my present implementation, I can do that by passing `true` (which will not be used in the end) as the value for such attribute like `dom(:input, type: "text", readonly: true)`, but that seems redundant and is also part of the reason that I have `case` statement in the code, making it slower. Is there a better way to do this?
- Are there any possible improvements to the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason of haml and most other nested stuff is that it is basically easy to look how your HTML is nested. I am assuming this but do you actually code HTML or do you do more backend stuff? The reason for it is that in nested style, you will see how your elements are nested(which is important to you if you are also writing the styles)

While it is quite easier to write

```
 .dom(:body).dom(:html)
```

it is difficult for a designer to see how the HTML flows without mapping and trying it to visualize in his head, whereas:

```
 %html
   %body
```

does that already with just one look.

Take not of a longer example:

```
 "This is a link to SO".dom(:a, href: "http://stackoverflow.com").dom(:body).dom(:html)
```

Would it be easier for you if say the client or you needed to add a clickable image to the link? How would you have done it? In haml it is easy as:

```
 %html
   %body
     %a{:href => "blah"}
       = image_tag("image.png")
```

Also, IMHO, writing `dom(:)` for each html tag is just as tedious as writing the closing tag for it(which HAML and the others fixed)

Again, these are just my opinions from an XHTML/CSS programmer(as opposed to a ruby programmer perspective)

And lastly, I would also think that this can be turned into a community wiki or something as this doesn't merit an exact answer and will probably spawn a lot of subjective ones like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the issue is mostly preference, and there is no particular performance issue? I might turn it into a community wiki as you suggest. I don't do extensive HTML coding. Just for my personal things. For me, the chain style is much easier to see than the nested style. If there is complicated structure, I would be using an array, and I will be indenting it to make the structure clear. The difference lies in whether you create a stack of nested tags at the beginning, or at the end. I feel the latter is easier for myself.

Comment: (By the way, I also feel more comfortable with reverse Polish notation than with infix or Polish). For your example with clickable image, I see no difficulty in replacing the initial string with `image_tag("image.png")`. The general idea behind me is that, tags and attributes are modifiers, not the main character. It is more natural to have the main string, and keep modifying it step by step. And for the suggestion that `dom` is tedious, I can think of a shorter method name.

Comment: hmmm, i guess that would be a valid argument for that. but yeah, it's more of a preference i guess if you prefer the reverse polish notation. HTML coders usually need to find the nest so i myself would be lost if I had that in reverse. I would also like to point out and ask how you would code child divs, or lis? The same as how you did with the tables?

Comment: also, what about inline markup? HAML has been criticized about it's "dirty" inline markup behavior so markdown is more preferred in this case. consider this link: http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/

Comment: @corroded Child div or li be be just the same. If there is only one child, it will be a chain. If there is more than one, I will be using an array. Thanks for the link. I am reading it. How do I turn this into a community wiki? I have never done it. I read the instructions in meta SO, but cannot seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: only mods i think can do that, i flagged it already for viewing but it needs more flags i guess

Comment: or you could check this out..apparently you can do it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: but looks like it's taken down? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192